# Python IEEE754 from bytearray

Tags: python, serial-port, arrays, ieee-754

I have a IEEE-754 number being sent to a Raspberry-Pi running Python3. Its sent as four serial bytes, but I can't figure out how to assemble this into a floating point number in Python.

Tried the various posts about using struct.pack but can't get this to give a sensible result?

Fairly new to Python, so it might be a easy answer?

Comment: This looks like a good question, although it might be helpful to include some code snippets as to what you've tried.

Answer (score 3):

You want `struct.unpack`, not `struct.pack`:

```
struct.unpack('<f', bytes) # little-endian
struct.unpack('>f', bytes) # big-endian
```

Comment: +1. But you probably want to make the endianness explicit. Of course you have to know what the endianness is. If the docs for the sender don't say, I'd try `!f` as a first guess, and if that gives me garbage, use `<f`.